# Setting lookupfield value client-side sharepoint

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, csom

Every article about how to do this is slightly different and can't seem to figure this out.

I have two lookup fields which are both present on my `Listitem`. I have reference to the list item here.

The lookup field values are exactly the same (they are different lists they points to). So if `Human Resources Document Category` has `Test1` as this value, it also exists in the lookup list for the field `HR Document Category`.

What I want to do is through CSOM update the field so if `Human Resources Document Category` says `Test1` I want to `HR Document Category` to show `Test1` as well.
[image]

```
foreach (var listitem in listItemCollection)
                {
                    //var boxedListItem = (SPListItem)listitem;
                    context.Load(listitem, f=>f.DisplayName, f=>f.FieldValuesAsText);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                //get reference to lookup field value
                var humanResourceDocCategory = "Human_x0020_Resources_x0020_Document_x0020_Category";
                FieldLookupValue originalCategoryValue = listitem[humanResourceDocCategory] as FieldLookupValue;

                //get ref to HR Document Category
                var hrDocCategory = "HR_x0020_Document_x0020_Category";
                listitem[hrDocCategory] = originalCategoryValue.LookupId;
                //listitem
                //listitem.ParseAndSetFieldValue(hrDocCategory, originalCategoryValue.Id);


                listitem.Update();
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine();



            }
```

This doesn't seem to work. If I do sometrhing like `listitem[hrDocCategory] = listitem[humanResourceDocCategory]` then, it doesn't add the value!!

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`originalCategoryValue` is already a `FieldLookupValue` object, so you should be able to directly assign that as the value of your lookup field.

```
listitem[hrDocCategory] = originalCategoryValue;
```

If that still doesn't work, you might need to verify that both lookup columns are pointing toward the same list.